# sequelize findAll with association and ordering in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get all the users with their master vendors, bookings and services order by booking_date via following way.

```
Users.findAll({
            where: { id: userId }, attributes: AttributesUser,
            include: [{
                model: MasterVendor, attributes: AttributesMasterVendor, required: true,
                include: [{
                    model: Bookings, where: { booking_state: jobStatus, booking_date: _date }, attributes: AttributesBooking,
                    include: [{ model: Services, attributes: attributesService, order: ['Bookings.booking_date'] }],
                }],
            }],
        });
```

But unfortunately, order by clause is not generating at all. But when when I try to get data order by names, It works perfectly

```
Users.findAll({
            where: { id: userId }, attributes: AttributesUser,
            include: [{
                model: MasterVendor, attributes: AttributesMasterVendor, required: true,
                include: [{
                    model: Bookings, where: { booking_state: jobStatus, booking_date: _date }, attributes: AttributesBooking,
                    include: { model: Services, attributes: attributesService }
                }]
            }],
            order: ['name'],
        });
```

Please suggest me, what I am doing wrong. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

include model name in order array.

```
Users.findAll({
            where: { id: userId }, attributes: AttributesUser,
            include: [{
                model: MasterVendor, attributes: AttributesMasterVendor, required: true,
                include: [{
                    model: Bookings, where: { booking_state: jobStatus, booking_date: _date }, attributes: AttributesBooking,
                    include: { model: Services, attributes: attributesService }
                }]
            }],
            order: [[Bookings, 'booking_date', 'DESC']],
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have resolved this issue. I have to add parent table(MasterVendor) before child table(Bookings) in order array

```
order: [[MasterVendor,Bookings, 'booking_date', 'ASC']],
```

Atlast,

```
Users.findAll({
            where: { id: userId }, attributes: AttributesUser,
            include: [{
                model: MasterVendor, attributes: AttributesMasterVendor, required: true, include: [{
                    model: Bookings, where: { booking_state: jobStatus, booking_date: _date }, attributes: AttributesBooking,
                    include: [{ model: Services, attributes: attributesService }],
                }],
            }],
            order: [[MasterVendor, Bookings, 'booking_date', 'ASC']],
        });
```